# How to make regex not to match the sequence of text, dot, text, but to match only text

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex:

```
[^/]+\/?\.\.\/
```

It is supposed to convert a relative to absolute url by replacing the above match with empty space.

Example:

```
http://abv.bg/path/../test
```

Should be converted to

```
http://abv.bg/test
```

Help me modify it so if I pass

```
http://abv.bg/../test
```

it doesn't remove the domain.

I need to make "[^/]+" not to match text with dot somewhere in the middle.

Comment: What result you are expecting?

Comment: You must be pretty good with backtracking to exploit PCRE regular expressions to achieve that. But I *think* this has been even already asked before. So probably some search on the site will give you some guidance. All I can say is that it is not trivial.

Comment: Loosely related: [prevent /.. user input](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9438824/367456)

Comment: directory names can contain periods

Comment: besides, what on earth is `http://abv.bg/../test` supposed to evaluate to?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
((^(?:http://)*[\w.]+)(/.*)(/[\w]+))
```

Replace with:

```
$2$4
```

#### [DEMO](http://regexr.com?31ugn)

Updated the regex and made the `http://` part optional.

Comment: @hakra Working fine for me, even the demo you provided. Could you tell me what you find is not working please?

Comment: Simle: `http://abv.bg/../asdas/../a/b/c/d/e/../test` is not `http://abv.bg/test` - in the demo it is. Hence not working. The only thin you managed is that `http://abv.bg/` is not getting removed. But the double-dots parts are not being resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Removing `(\/[^\/.]+)?\/\.\.` satisfies your requirements, but mind my comments.